# Swap Multiple Images on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I am wanting to swap multiple images on mouseover and am looking for a way to do this. I am looking to 'light up' multiple stars. The code below works fine for one, but what is the best way to light up e.g 3 stars when the cursor hovers over the third star?

```
<div class="rating" data-value="4">
 <img src="star.png"/>
 <img src="star.png"/>
 <img src="star.png"/>
 <img src="star.png"/>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
$(".rating > img") .mouseover(function () {
            this.src= "star-on.png";
        }).mouseout(function () {
            this.src= "star.png";

});
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, you can give each a class like `star-1`... `star-4` and loop through all the stars you want to highlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by getting the index of the star within the set that was moused over and then replacing the correct amount of stars based on that index:

```js
$(".rating > img").mouseover(function () {
    // Get the index of the star that is being hovered over
    var idx = $("img").index(this);
   
    // Loop only over the stars that should be highlighted and highlight them.
    // Use the index to know how many to loop over
    for(var i = 0; i < idx + 1; i++){
      // "Light up" the star:
      $(".rating > img")[i].src= "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d8/Full_Star_Blue.svg/2000px-Full_Star_Blue.svg.png";
    }
  }).mouseout(function () {
        
    // Turn off all stars
    $(".rating > img").each(function(){
    this.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Empty_Star.svg/1024px-Empty_Star.svg.png"
  });

});
```

```css
img {
 width:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating" data-value="4">
 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Empty_Star.svg/1024px-Empty_Star.svg.png">
 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Empty_Star.svg/1024px-Empty_Star.svg.png">
 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Empty_Star.svg/1024px-Empty_Star.svg.png">
 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Empty_Star.svg/1024px-Empty_Star.svg.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to mention that this is easily achieveable with pure css and flexbox features:

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}

body {padding:30px;}

.stars {
  padding:10px;
  background:#fff;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
}

.stars .star {
  flex: 0 1 50px;
  background:red;
  padding:20px;
}

.stars .star:hover, .stars .star:hover ~ .star {
  background:salmon;
}
```

```html
<div class="stars">
  <div class="star">4</div>
  <div class="star">3</div>
  <div class="star">2</div>
  <div class="star">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post code at 3rd party links as those links can become broken over time. Just create a code snippet right here.

Comment: Flexbox is not required for this solution.

Comment: Of course is not required, but is a good practise in this particular situation. Stylistic aspects should be defined in stylesheet, so I wanted to show better and easier solution rather than just be strict with OP tags, because it's more educational.

Comment: Huh? Just change the the `.star` elements to be `span` elements that are styled to: `display:inline-block`. I don't see how Flexbox is a good practice here. It's not that it's bad, but the addition of it doesn't improve the code. It's an unnecessary addition that implies that it is somehow relevant here, which it's not.

Comment: Thanks to `flex-direction:row-reverse` and `~` selector you don't have to use any javascript to style that control. You wouldn't had that control of element with just `inline-block` because you can not select "previous" elements unless you set `direction: rtl`, but still - why involve js?

Comment: You miss my point. I'm not comparing your answer with a JS answer. I'm just saying that Flexbox is not required to do this in pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in plain vanilla JavaScript:

```js
var stars = document.querySelector('.stars')

stars.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  var target = event.target
  var index = target.dataset.index

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var star = stars.querySelector('[data-index="' + i + '"]')
    star.classList.toggle('active', i <= index)
  }
})

stars.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var star = stars.querySelector('[data-index="' + i + '"]')
    star.classList.toggle('active', false)
  }
})
```

```css
.star {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}

.star.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="stars">
  <div class="star" data-index="0"></div>
  <div class="star" data-index="1"></div>
  <div class="star" data-index="2"></div>
  <div class="star" data-index="3"></div>
  <div class="star" data-index="4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post code to 3rd party sites as those links can become broken over time. Just create a "code snippet" right here so everything anyone needs to understand your answer is right here, in one place.

Comment: @ScottMarcus gotcha

Comment: You may want to also consider adding semicolons to the end of your statements instead of relying on the JS runtime to do it (which has well-known edge cases where it will be done incorrectly and cause bugs).